# Does Cognito automatically signup federated users?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

If we allow users to signin with Google using Cognito Federated Identities, will Cognito automatically add the users attributes to the Cognito user pool?

In other words will we be able to go to the user pool and see their first name, last name, email, etc.

Or do we need to do this manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF you are using User Pools along with federated identity, you have to [map](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-attribute-mapping.html) the attributes to your user pool table.

There is also a scenerio where you use identity pool to exchange federated identity tokens for temporary AWS credentials without adding the user to user pool.